# Как сделать ссылку на произвольный адрес на яндекс картах из email?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, email

Как сделать ссылку на яндекс карту из email? Приходит заказ от клиента с адресом доставки и при клике на него хотелось бы попадать на яндекс карту.

В документации есть только с помощью подключения  geolink  на html странице.
Пока вижу только такое решение - только получение координат до отправки email и вставка в письмо.
Но может быть есть решение чтобы просто в url передать адрес в текстовом виде?

Comment: В Яндекс.Почте такой функционал уже реализован. В теле письма Вы пишете адрес словами, и получатель сможет нажать на этот текст как на  гиперссылку, откроется карта. Вам не нужно ничего дополнительно настраивать.

Comment: Речь не о яндекс почте. В моем случае письма с сайта уходят не на яндекс, но даже если бы они уходили на яндекс, то читаться могут с помощью outlook, airmail, spark и т.д, а не через интерфейс яндекса. Поэтому нужно формировать ссылку.

Answer (score 1):

У Яндекс.Карт есть URL-схема. [Вот документация](https://tech.yandex.ru/yandex-apps-launch/maps/doc/concepts/yandexmaps-web-docpage/?from=SO)

Если у вас есть только адрес, то можно подставлять его в таком формате:

```
https://yandex.ru/maps/?text={адрес}
```

И формировать ссылку, например, такую:

[https://yandex.ru/maps/?text=Москва, ул. Льва Толстого, 16](https://yandex.ru/maps/?text=%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0,%20%D1%83%D0%BB.%20%D0%9B%D1%8C%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE,%2016)